# Does a Master in Liberal Arts help in someone's CV if he/she targets in Academia?

Tags: masters

Does a Master in Liberal Arts help in someone's CV if he/she targets in Academia? Has anything to offer to the CV? Also, what is the difference between "Master of Liberal Arts", "MSc", "Master's" and "Master of Engineering"? Which is better for a CV?

**UPDATE:** Is it better to get a **Master on Liberal Arts** from one of the top 10 Universities of the World, or a **MSc** from a local, not so famous University? Both Master's on the same field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to teach at the university level you need a doctorate in almost every field. A masters alone might be enough for a very temporary part time position, but not more. The nature of the masters done prior to a doctorate has little importance.

In a field like history or literature, a Masters in Liberal Arts might be entirely appropriate. For engineering, not so much without other qualifications.

A masters of some sort might do for a Junior (or Community) College in the US (or not), which is normally the first two years of a university program. But very few can go beyond that with a masters. And many faculty even there have doctorates.

The "difference" is due to different traditions in different universities and in different countries. Don't put too much emphasis on the designation as each of them can be applied to a fairly broad range of topics. Even "Engineering" is a pretty broad topic.

Moreover, in some places the same program can result in either an MA or a MS (like MSc). My math program had such a choice. But it was the fact that it was a MA in mathematics that enabled my progression to a doctorate in math. And, while my undergraduate math program was hosted by the engineering school, it might just as well have been within the Liberal Arts school. Just a historical artifact. That same choice wouldn't be true for History or for Physics, though.

A Masters might be essential or helpful for admission to a doctoral program. Very important in, say, Germany. Not very important (or especially common) in US.

---

WRT your update. Top universities worldwide are well regarded but both difficult to get in to and have very rigorous programs. That is a plus. But one can learn a lot at less prestigious places. It is more a question of what you do than where you go. A joke in the US is that "there is nothing more dangerous (nothing worse...) than a C student from Yale".

Moreover, most universities will want to see your transcripts which lists your courses and grades. The actual designation of the degree is less important, though the rigor of the program, if known, could be a factor. People are pretty good at making distinctions rather than being "wowed" by some titles.